# Difference between Error and Exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have referred many books and even Java docs provided by Oracle but still I have a confusion that what makes Error class different from Exception class.
Can you guys please explain this as we can catch and handle both.

```
class Handle{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         try{
             int k = 10/0;
         }catch(Exception e){
         }
         try{
             //some statement
         }catch(Error e){
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813614/what-is-difference-between-errors-and-exceptions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error

Answer (score 2):

It's a semantic difference. An `Error` is something that is impossible to survive from (think `OutOfMemoryError`), whereas an `Exception` could possibly be handled somehow.

Comment: but we can catch the error and inside the catch we can use the garbage collector call to free the memory

Comment: @HarshitGupta Not really. The garbage collector will attempt to free any possible memory before throwing an `OOME`, so catching it would be useless.

Comment: So there is no other difference then this?

Comment: There's no functional difference, no. It's just an agreement that `Errors` are serious and `Exceptions` are less serious.

Comment: Ok can you help me with one more question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455405/